# Struct de 20 estudiantes me marca error: [Error] expected primary-expression before '[' token

Tags: c++, estructuras-de-datos, dev-c++

Debo hacer una estructura de 20 estudiantes en la que pueda almacenar sus nombres, un carnet, y sus notas o calificaciones. Luego, si se desea asignarle una nota a cierto estudiante preguntar por el carnet y si este existe dar la opcion de asignarsea, de lo contrario decirle al usuario que no existe. Esto es lo que he probado pero me da este error

> [Error] expected primary-expression before '[' token

¿Alguien me podría ayudar a ver por qué se da este error? No se si tiene que ver con el orden en mi codigo Por favor, se los agradecería mucho

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct Estudiantes{
char Nombre[255];
int Carnet;
int Nota;
};

int main ()
{
struct Estudiantes datos[20];
int Carnet;
int i;
for(i=0;i<20;i++);
{
    printf("Ingrese el nombre, el carnet y la nota respectivamente del estudiante %d:\n ", i++);
    scanf("%c", Estudiantes[i].Nombre);
    scanf("%d",&Estudiantes[i].Carnet);
    scanf("%d",&Estudiantes[i].Nota);
    
}

printf("Ingrese el carnet del estudiante al que desea asignarle una nota: \n");
scanf("%d", &Carnet);
{
    if(Carnet==Estudiantes[i].Carnet)
    {
        printf("Ingrese la nota que desea asignarle: ");
        scanf("%d",&(Estudiantes[i].Carnet));
    }
    else
    {
        printf("El carnet no existe");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hay varias cosas que están mal con el código.

Primero, en el loop para ingresar la información de los estudiantes. La estructura en donde vas a ingresar los datos se llama `datos`, no `Estudiantes`. Además, el `%c` solo lee un carácter, y necesitas que sea una cadena, por eso `%s`.

Ahora, para encontrar el estudiante usando el Carnet, tienes que hacer otro *loop*, y comparar el número de carnet con cada estudiante hasta encontrar el que corresponde. Si sales del *loop* y aún no lo encuentras, entonces no existe. Para esto puedes usar un *boolean*.

En el `printf` en el que lees el nombre no debes usar `i++`, esto aumenta el contador que estás usando, usa `i + 1`.

```c
struct Estudiantes {
   char Nombre[255];
   int Carnet;
   int Nota;
};

int main () {
   int num_est = 20;
   Estudiantes datos[num_est];
   int Carnet;
   bool existe = false;
   int i;

   for(i = 0; i < num_est; i++) {
       printf("Ingrese el nombre, el carnet y la nota respectivamente del estudiante %d: ", i+1);
       scanf("%s", datos[i].Nombre);
       scanf("%d",&datos[i].Carnet);
       scanf("%d",&datos[i].Nota);
   }

   printf("Ingrese el carnet del estudiante al que desea asignarle una nota: \n");
   scanf("%d", &Carnet);


   for(i = 0; i < num_est; i++) {
      if(Carnet == datos[i].Carnet){
         existe = true;
         printf("Ingrese la nota que desea asignarle: ");
         scanf("%d",&(datos[i].Carnet));
      }
   }

   if (!existe) {
       printf("El carnet no existe");
   }
}
```

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflow

Answer (score 2):

Lo primero, en C++ no hace falta usar `struct` para declarar variables. Así que esto:

```
struct Estudiantes datos[20];
```

Queda más C++ así

```
Estudiantes datos[20];
```

Luego fíjate que la variable se llama `datos` ... tu estás accediendo a `Estudiantes`:

```
scanf("%c", Estudiantes[i].Nombre);
scanf("%d",&Estudiantes[i].Carnet);
scanf("%d",&Estudiantes[i].Nota);
```

Basta con reemplazar `Estudiantes`, que es un tipo, por `datos`, que es la variable:

```
scanf("%c", datos[i].Nombre);
scanf("%d",&datos[i].Carnet);
scanf("%d",&datos[i].Nota);
```

Aunque ya que estamos en C++, sería preferible usar `std::cin` y `std::cout`:

```
std::cout << "Ingrese el nombre, el carnet y la nota respectivamente del estudiante "
          << i << ":\n ";
std::cin >> datos[i].Nombre >> datos[i].Carnet >> datos[i].Nota;
```